# Can you restore Roman Empire as a pagan?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am playing the Old Gods DLC, started in the north as a Pomeranian duke, formed the Wendish Empire and have now reconquered much of the Byzantine Empire, whose title I have usurped. I stayed as a (reformed) pagan. I seem to remember that the Byzantine Emperor has two unique decisions available: mend the schism and restore the Roman Empire. Being a pagan, it makes perfect sense that mend the schism is not available to me. However, I would have expected the Restore the Roman Empire decisions to be available. To clarify, I am not saying the decision is greyed out, it is not listed as a possible decision *at all*.

Are there some conditions I must fulfill before the decision will appear as an option (even if greyed out)? It would be great to know the exact list of conditions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to be emperor of Byzantium and be Christian for the decision to restore the Roman Empire to show up. From `decisions/realm_decisions.txt`:

```
restore_roman_empire = {
    [...]
    potential = {
        has_dlc = "Legacy of Rome"
        age = 16
        prisoner = no
        NOT = { trait = incapable }
        has_landed_title = e_byzantium
        religion_group = christian
    }
    [...]
}
```

If you don't like that, you can simply remove or comment out the `religion_group` line.

Comment: Alternatively, you could change it to `OR = { AND = { religion_group = christian [newline] religion = hellenic_pagan }` (or something along those lines) to enable the Hellenic religion to reform the empire as well.

Answer (score 2):

As of the release of Holy Fury, you can now restore the Roman Empire as both an unreformed and reformed Hellenic.

Answer (score 1):

[To restore the Roman Empire you must control Rome and its former territory.](http://ckiiwiki.com/Roman_Empire_walkthrough) That means taking over Italy and the Holy Land. Until you control the old Roman Empire, you won't have the option to restore it.